Column of h2 elements takes width of the biggest, how to prevent?
I have a column of H2 elements that I rotate through with a CSS transform.
I need the background color of the H2 element to only cover the H2 element and text. There is a line running behind the text and right now the shortest element's background is the length of the longest and covers the line behind it with a blank space after the text.


.title {
  margin-top: -30px;
  font-size: calc(17px + (0.01* 100vw));
}

.slogan {
  background-color: #29335cff;
}


/* TEXT FLIPPER */

.text-container {
  height: 2.45rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text-flip {
  animation: text-flip 5s cubic-bezier(0.23, 0.8, 0.32, 1.2) infinite;
}

.text-flip h2 {
  background-color: #29335cff;
}

@keyframes text-flip {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateY(-77%);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateY(-25%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
<div class='title d-flex'>

  <div class='px-2 slogan'>
    <h2>
      TAP COCKTAILS MADE
    </h2>
  </div>

  <div class='text-container '>
    <div class='text-flip d-flex justify-content-start flex-column'>
      <h2 class=''>EASY</h2>
      <h2 class=''>PROFITABLE</h2>
      <h2 class=''>TASTY</h2>
      <h2 class=''>YOUR OWN</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Headings are block-elements by default, they take up the entire available width.

/* Container styles */
.text-container {
  height: 2.45rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

/* Set up the text flip animation */
.text-flip {
  animation: text-flip 10s cubic-bezier(0.23, 0.8, 0.32, 1.2) infinite;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}

/* Individual text styles */
.text-flip h2 {
  background-color: #29335cff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: max-content; /* Makes each item take only as much width as its content */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px; /* Optional: adds padding inside the background */
}

/* Calculate the max width and ensure all items have the same width */
.text-flip h2:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* Animation keyframes */
@keyframes text-flip {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translateY(-200%);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateY(-300%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}


Thanks for the quick response! Unfortiunately the background color of the shortest H2 element still takes up the space of the longest H2 element.

@ThomasDoll-Datema Sorry, updated the answer with css. Snippet messed it up for me

Headings are block elements, hence, they are taking full width.
I am updating my earlier answer with the thing you're looking for.
<div class='title d-flex'>

   <div class='px-2 slogan'>
      <h2>
         TAP COCKTAILS MADE
      </h2>
   </div>

   <div class='text-container '>
      <div class='text-flip d-flex justify-content-start flex-column'>
         <h2 class=''>EASY</h2>
         <h2 class=''>PROFITABLE</h2>
         <h2 class=''>TASTY</h2>
         <h2 class=''>YOUR OWN</h2>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

.title {
   margin-top: -30px;
   font-size: calc(17px + (0.01 * 100vw));
}

.slogan {
   background-color: #29335cff;
}

/* TEXT FLIPPER */

.text-container {
   height: 2.45rem;
   background-color: transparent;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.text-flip {
   animation: text-flip 5s cubic-bezier(0.23, 0.8, 0.32, 1.2) infinite;
}

.text-flip h2 {
   background-color: #ff0000ff;
   display: inline;
}
.text-flip h2:after {
   content: "";
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   background: #fff;
}

@keyframes text-flip {
   0% {
      transform: translateY(0);
   }
   20% {
      transform: translateY(-77%);
   }
   40% {
      transform: translateY(-50%);
   }
   60% {
      transform: translateY(-25%);
   }
   100% {
      transform: translateY(0);
   }
}

Hope, this helps.

FYI: You can use the button Copy snippet to answer

@DarkBee, yes, but I need time to check that thoroughly.  Thank you for suggestion.

Thanks for the quick response! Unfortiunately the background color of the shortest H2 element still takes up the space of the longest H2 element.

@ThomasDoll-Datema Please check this.https://codepen.io/ansarinaeemakhtar/pen/RwXggBJ
